# Changing attribute of child SVG element in JS

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a page with an SVG object and some Javascript. When I click on a specific G element, I want the fill colour of any subelements in that G element to change - but only the ones matching a specific class.

SVG:

```
<g transform="translate(120, 40)" onclick="routeButton(this);">
  <ellipse cx="0" cy="0" rx="14" ry="14" fill="red" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" />
  <ellipse class="nxButtonFace" cx="0" cy="0" rx="11" ry="11" fill="darkslategray" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" />
  <polygon points="-1,-5 -6,0 -1,5" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="black" />
  <polygon points="6,-5 1,0 6,5" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
</g>
```

Script:

```
    function routeButton(item) {
        for (var idx = 0; idx < item.childNodes.length; idx++) {
            var child = item.childNodes[idx];
            if (child.hasOwnProperty('classList') && child.classList.contains('nxButtonFace')) {
                child.setAttribute('fill', 'white');
            }
        }
    };
```

So, in this case, only the second ellipse should change. However, upon clicking the G element, nothing happens as none of the children seem to be elements with classList as a property. Removing that hasOwnProperty check fails the child.classList method (null). FWIW, item.childNodes.length is 9, not 4.

What am I missing, please? Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `.children` instead of `.childNodes`?

Comment: Using .children pops up an error 'Unable to get property "length" of undefined or null reference' (ie item.children.length in the "for").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about just using CSS?

```
function routeButton(item) {
  item.setAttribute("class", "selected");
};


.selected > .nxButtonFace {
  fill: white;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to understand how to do it in purely JS and SVG first but this does work, and is very concise - and works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No element ever has the *own* property `classList`. They’re all inherited from `Element`.

Just iterate over `children` instead of `childNodes`.

Simply using

```
item.querySelectorAll(":scope > .nxButtonFace")
  .forEach((child) => child.setAttribute('fill', 'white'));
```

as the function body may also be enough, if browser support was irrelevant.

If that does not work (e.g. [due to compatibility reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children#Browser_compatibility)), just check `child.classList` instead of `child.hasOwnProperty('classList')` in your `if` condition:

```
if (child.classList && child.classList.contains('nxButtonFace'))
```

If [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility) is also not supported (e.g. with SVG not until Edge 16.16299), use a polyfill or check `if (child.className && child.className.indexOf('nxButtonFace') > -1)` instead.

Comment: `child.classList.contains()` throws an exception: unable to get property 'contains' of undefined or null reference. `item.children` is also null (thanks - now I understand why, it's IE9).

Comment: Does your `if` condition look like `if (child.classList && child.classList.contains('nxButtonFace'))`? Probably [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility) is also not supported. Use an alternative or a polyfill for that.

Comment: Hmm, I need to dig into this a bit more - it's a WPF WebBrowser component and a quick search suggests it may not even be IE9 by default. I will dig further tomorrow - thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @GeoffM IE9 doesn’t support a lot of stuff that you’re using. The compatibility is even worse for SVG elements.